# Naming layers in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using a pre-trained keras model ( Convolutional network) and I am retraining this model again on my dataset.
Now, I need to get the output of some layers, to visualize the gradient activation. I just found out that every trained model has different naming of layers. for example, the input layer in one model is: `input_7 (InputLayer)` and in another model is `input_5 (InputLayer)`.

Do you know how to prevent this bad behavior? How can I keep the same naming without the need to manually name all the layers, as I have more than 53 convolutional layers?

Comment: Could you share the code to make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: I am using the code from this repo, just doing some minimal changes, [code](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/train.py#L105), so my question is how to initiate the naming in keras? thanks

Comment: I solved the problem, it was just because I used jupyter. I was running model. summary and the numbers related to layer names are incrementing with every call to model.summary. I restart the kernel and I get the correct names.

Comment: @Desmanda model.summary() doesn't change the layer names, what could have happened is that you were recreating the model each time you run that cell.

Comment: you are right, I was recreating the model again by running the cell multi times. my bad, I am not used to jupyter. thanks!